# Java Applet slows down when mouse is moved

Tags: java, event-handling, applet

I have a Java Applet with a Thread, MouseListerner and MouseMotionListener.

When the mouse is dragged something is drawn on the applet and then it falls down.
That does work, but when the mouse is moved and not pressed, the falling object does not move fluent.

The Thread calls the repaint function

```
while(running){
  repaint();
}
```

The mouseMoved function is empty, mouseDragged calls repaint.
I hope someone knows this issue, thank you

Comment: 1) `while(running){ repaint(); }`  Don't do that without a `wait()` 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) This millennium, use Swing rather than AWT components. 4) This should probably be a frame launched from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) (rather than an embedded applet, which is trickier).

Answer (score 1):

You are hogging CPU (unnecesaruly) with your main thread.  Since you do not need updates faster that every 40 milliseconds, and maybe every 80 will be enough, you should rework your main loop to something like:

```
   /**
 * internal game loop method.
 */
public void updateGameState() {
    lastFrameTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // as long as we run we move
    while (state == GameState.RUNNING) {
        currentFrame++;
        timeNow = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // sleep until this frame is scheduled
        long l = lastFrameTime + FRAME_DELAY - timeNow;
        updatePositions();
        redraw();
        //System.err.println("............. delay:" + l);
        if (l > 0L) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(l);
            }
            catch (Exception exception) {
            }
        } else {
            // something long kept us from updating, reset delays
            lastFrameTime = timeNow;
            l = FRAME_DELAY;
        }

        //System.err.println("lft: " + lastFrameTime + " tn: " + timeNow);
        lastFrameTime = timeNow + l;
        // be polite, let others play
        Thread.yield();
    }
    ///System.err.println("leave game loop");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, I'll try to implement them